# Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js): warning: Parsing error: Unexpected character "EOF" (prettier/prettier) at

Tags: vue.js, eol, prettier

I have a problem with compiling a vue module in Visual Studio code. During compilation It has always returned the same warning, although I'm using autoformat. I have already changed CRLF to LF, however it didn't help. Can somebody help me, please?

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
warning: Parsing error: Unexpected character "EOF" (prettier/prettier) at src\components\ViewEmployees.vue:34:2:
  32 |   }
  33 | };
> 34 |
     | ^


1 warning found.
```

Comment: Solved. I forgot to add </script> tag and new line at the end :-)